# EditTextPreference make not clickable and gray

Tags: android

I would like to make the `EditTextPreference` not clickable and gray programmatically on demand.

```
<EditTextPreference android:key="..." android:icon="..." android:title="..." />
```

The following code is partly fine but does not make the button gray color:

```
PREF.setEnabled(false);
```

Additonally I would like if someones clicks the gray button is shows `Toast` message "no premission" - How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you disable the item click then by default it will turn gray and it will not listen to clicks. So, you cannot show any toast after you disable it. Actually, you don't have to because gray means its not clickable or disabled thats the way it works.

Comment: It is not an answer to my question. Plus not on all phones it is gray by default